# Applying the power rule to $(3x)^{-4}$

Tags: calculus

To solve this the book does this:

$\frac{d}{dx}(3x)^{-4}$
$=$
$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(3x)^{4}} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{81x^{4}} = \frac{-4}{81}\cdot x^{-5}$

But when I tried doing this:

$\frac{d}{dx}(3x)^{-4} = -4(3x)^{-5} = \frac{-4}{243}\cdot x^{-5}$

How come my method doesn't work? Am I missing something or is this a mistake?

Comment: Hint: chain rule

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the chain rule in your method. So you have to multiply by the derivative of $3x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think about it... We have a *constant coefficient* $3^{-4}$. Let's bring it in front of the derivative before applying the power rule.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(3x)^{-4} &= (3)^{-4}\frac{d}{dx}x^{-4} \\
&= (3)^{-4}(-4)x^{-5} \\
&= \frac{-4}{81}x^{-5}
\end{align*}$$